How to enable clang-tidy to inspect header files and related interfaces
Currently we are integrating clang-tidy into our project and we found that it has troubles when we introduce interfaces to classes (in multiple files).
Consider following code
//driver_interface.hpp
class IDriver
{
public:
    virtual void doOperation() = 0;
};

//specific_driver.hpp
#include "driver_interface.hpp"
class SpecificDriver : public IDriver
{
public:
    void doOperation() override { 
        // do something
    };
};

//driver_executor.hpp
#include "specific_driver.hpp"
class DriverExecutor
{
    public:
    DriverExecutor(IDriver &driver) : driver(driver) {}

    private:
    IDriver &driver;
};

int main()
{
   SpecificDriver specDriver;
   DriverExecutor executor(specDriver);
 
   return 0;
}

Ignore the fact that speficic_driver.hpp is included directly from DriverExecutor class. It is intended code smell to keep the example short, but DriverExecutor is able to reach IDriver interface.
Even though this code is working, clang-tidy has problems with resolving interfaces. Analyzing the file driver_executor.hpp reports following error:
no header providing "IDriver" is directly included

This can be suppressed by disabling misc-include-cleaner doc, but I would prefer to somehow guide clang-tidy to traverse trough include hierarchy.
Is it even possible or this is just dead end?

From the doc, it expects direct #include or proper usage of IWYU pragmas if appropriate.

You might deactivate missingincludes (as-if it is really missing code won't compile)
